# If $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, can $\sum (a_n - a_{n+1})$ still diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$. It is surely the case that $\sum a_n$ can diverge: we can just take $\frac{1}{n}$, which converges to $0$, is Cauchy, but diverges. Similarly, $(a_n)$ could converge to something that isn't $0$, so by the Divergence Test, $\sum a_n$ diverges. Similarly, it seems to me that if we had
\begin{align*}
\sum (a_n - a_{n+1}) := \sum \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \sum \frac{1}{n} - \sum\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align*}
then we get a result of the form $\infty - \infty$, which can't possibly converge. Then again, it's possible that this series telescopes.

My question I suppose is: is the property that $\sum (a_n - a_{n+1})$ converges not necessarily true given that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy?

Answer (score 4):

Note that we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^N(a_n-a_{n+1})=a_1-a_{N+1}$$

So, we only require that $a_n$ converges to guarantee that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n-a_{n+1})$ converges.

---

In general , one cannot write legitimately that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-a_{n+1})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}$.

**If** the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, **THEN** we can write $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-a_{n+1})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}$$

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about why we need $a_n$ to converge? It seems to me that we would add and subtract terms ad infinitum and be left with only $a_1$ regardless. Does it have to do with the tail of the series tending to zero? Even then, if I am not mistaken, that's a necessary but not sufficient condition for convergence.

Comment: @Matt.P An infinite series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ is defined as the limit of the partial sums, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N b_n$.  If $b_n=a_n-a_{n+1}$, the partial sums of $b_n$ become $a_1-a_{N+1}$.  Now, if $\lim_{N\to\infty}a_{N+1}$ exists, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ exists.  And we are done.